# SQLite adds NULL values into NOT NULL columns

Tags: php, sqlite, null

I'm creating a table with NOT NULL columns like  this:

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL);`

but SQLite is happy to add NULL values to those columns:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

// ---

const DB_FILE = "auth.db";
//$username = "john";
//$password = "secret";
$username = '';
$password = '';

// ---

// open db
//$db = new PDO('sqlite:'.DB_FILE);
$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');

// set attributes
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// create the table
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL);");

$statement = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES (:Username,:Password);";    
$query = $db->prepare($statement);
$query->bindValue(':Username', $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$query->bindValue(':Password', $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$ok = $query->execute();

$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Users');
if (!$result) die ("oops!"); // will not produce anything when errormode is on

echo "<pre>\n";

foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo "Id: " . $row['Id'] . "\n";
    echo "Username: " . $row['Username'] . "\n";
    echo "Password: " . $row['Password'] . "\n";
}

$db = NULL;

?>
```

SQLite shouldn't allow that. What am I doing wrong?

**Update on 2013-04-23 ~00:35 Z**

The following concerns comments on the answer from Diamond Geezer.

SQLite stops the execution of these statements:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('','');");
$db->exec("INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('a','aa');");
$db->exec("SELECT * FROM Users;");
```

But not these ones:

```
$username = '';
$password = '';
$statement = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES (:Username,:Password);";    
$query = $db->prepare($statement);
$query->bindValue(':Username', $username, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$query->bindValue(':Password', $password, SQLITE3_TEXT);
$ok = $query->execute();
```

I think it must have something to do with preparing the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Username and password are not NULL; they are zero-length strings:

```
$username = '';
$password = '';
```

And this is why they get inserted.

In response to your comment, you can stop zero-length strings being inserted by using a CHECK constraint as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users 
(
  Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  Username TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL CHECK(Username<>''), 
  Password TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(Password<>'')
);
```

Here it is in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/36bcd/4). The statement: `INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('','');` fails with the error: *could not execute statement due to a constraint failure (19 constraint failed)*, whereas the statement: `INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password) VALUES ('a','aa');` succeeds.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my question. Do you, by the way, know how do I tell SQLite to reject empty strings?

Comment: @jsmith6 I have updated my answer to include an example of using a CHECK constraint to stop zero-length strings being inserted into the Username and Password columns. I've split the statement as multiple for ease of reading.

Comment: Ahhh, I tried that but it failed because I prepare the statement. Is there a way to have CHECK there but also pepare statements?